# Android Horizontal Scrollbar is clipping text

Tags: android, view, textview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a ScrollView which contains a linear layout. The linear layout contains several textviews, all of which have the bottom 25% of their text cut off (see picture). I would like the text to be fully visible, with no scroll bar visible.

My assumption at this point is that the horizontal scroll bar is taking up that space.

I have hidden the scroll bar itself (as desired), but the blank space where it used to be occludes the text in the ScrollView.

- Disabling the scrollbars programmatically has not worked.
- Increasing the layout margin of the linear layout has no effect.
- Increasing the padding of the scrollview has no effect.

[image]

Here is the relevant xml from my layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/ValuePicker" android:layout_width="160dp" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_height="40dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/ValueLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/value1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="A" android:padding="8dp" android:clickable="true"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:text="2" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:id="@+id/value2" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="25dp" android:padding="8dp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/value3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="3" android:padding="8dp" android:clickable="true" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/value4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="4" android:padding="8dp" android:clickable="true" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"></TextView>
        <TextView android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:id="@+id/value5" android:text="5" android:padding="8dp" android:clickable="true" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"></TextView>
        <TextView android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:id="@+id/value6" android:text="6" android:padding="8dp" android:clickable="true" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="7"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="8"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value9" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="9"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value10" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="10"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value11" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="J"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value12" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Q"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:padding="8dp" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="25dp" android:id="@+id/value13" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="K"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using padding. Try removing the padding from bottom. If you want to keep the padding then increase the height from 40dp to 45dp.

So size and padding are the issue.

Soln 1 (if you can increase size):

Increase size of `HorizontalScrollView` and `LinearLayout` to something like `android:layout_height="60dp"` so that text is not clipped.

Soln 2 (if can get rid vertical padding):

The below layout works fine for `2` where i removed vertical padding. When you just saying padding=5 it will pad it all around.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="25dp" >
        </TextView>
```

Now choose the appropriate soln as per your need.

Comment: Removing the vertical padding worked perfectly! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="match_parent or fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ValueLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"> and remove the gravity.
```

Comment: The parent is the root layout (a relative layout). I wouldn't want the scroll view to take up the entire vertical screen space.